# Do I need to reimplement all the constructor of a base class even if a derived class has no member variables?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Let's assume I have a base class

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    Base(int i, double j);
    Base(int i, double j, char ch);

    virtual void print();

private:
    int m;
    double l;
    char n;
};
```

And I want to derive a class which overrides the print function but apart from that is exactly the same as the base class.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void print();
};
```

Is there a way I can use all the constructors of the base class on the derived class without me rewriting all of them for the Derived class?

Comment: Thing is I was deriving a huge class with several constructor and I felt a bit overwhelmed but now that you are mentioning it I should try with smaller cases. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since C++11, you may use `using` for that:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base; // use all constructors of base.

    void print() override;
};
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/KDlSGC)

Comment: This requires a capable C++11 compiler, though.

Comment: This names a constructor of `Base`, which is illegal (at least, before C++11).

Comment: @SebastianRedl: We're halfway through 2015 now. That means that, although good reasons exist that one can't use C++11 or newer, they must be explicitly stated in the question and shall not be assumed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't mean to criticize the answer; in fact I upvoted it. It still needs to be pointed out though, because Microsoft's latest stable release, Visual Studio 2013, doesn't support inherited constructors. (VS 2015 does.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I don't disagree with that sentiment

Answer (score 1):

You can call the base class's constructors. So if you define `Base` as follows.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};
    Base(int i, double j) : m{i}, l{j} {};
    Base(int i, double j, char ch) : m{i}, l{j}, n{ch} {};

    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; };

private:
    int m;
    double l;
    char n;
};
```

Then you can have `Derived` have analogous constructors that use the `Base` constructors to initialize the inherited member variables.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base() {}
    Derived(int i, double j) : Base(i, j) {}
    Derived(int i, double j, char ch) : Base(i, j, ch) {}

    void print() override { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; };
};
```

As an example

```
int main()
{
    Base b1{};
    Base b2{1, 2};
    Base b3{1, 2, 'a'};

    Derived d1{};
    Derived d2{1, 2};
    Derived d3{1, 2, 'a'};
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly I still need to know all the constructors of the base class if I want them to work also in the derived class.

Comment: @RDGuida: _If_ you're stuck with an ancient compiler, yes. If you can stay up-to-date then there is a really easy solution.

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit, if you have access to a modern compiler then [Jarod42's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30801791/2296458) is the easiest and most maintainable solution. This solution works if you have to use it, but it's a pain in the butt to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way by means of delegating constructors and the using declaration as it is shown in the demonstrative program provided that your compiler supports C++ 2011. Otherwise you have to define the constructors yourself.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() : Base( 0, 0.0, '\0' ) {}
    Base(int i, double j) : Base( i, j, '\0' ) {}
    Base(int i, double j, char ch) : m( i ), l( j ), n( ch ) {}
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void print() const { std::cout << m << ' ' << l << ' ' << n << std::endl; }

private:
    int m;
    double l;
    char n;
};    

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
    void print() const override { Base::print(); } 
};

int main()
{
    Derived( 65, 65.65, 'A' ).print();
}
```

The program output is

```
65 65.65 A
```

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Usually I do that for myself. So I am not late.:)

Comment: *“A wizard is never late, nor is he early, he arrives precisely when he means to.”*